# FVG318 used as a Wireless Access Point

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

My apologies in advance: I am a software developer with just enough networking knowledge to get into trouble :)

So I had a cable modem/router setup through my ISP right in my office. They sold me on TV via IP but when they went to install it, "The Router will have to be placed by the TV". This means all my wired ports were lost.

I have an Net Gear FVG318 Wireless Router that I was using as a GuestNetwork. So I had hardwired it into the modem/router and anyone could connect to that more freely. In all those documents it says it has a "wireless access point". To me that means it can connect wirelessly to a wired network. I havent been able to figure out how to do it yet. Isnt that what a "wireless access point" is?

Is there any way to use my existing hardware to wirelessly connect it to my network without physically using a wire across the house. If not what device would you recommend to do this. I always thought thats what a wireless access point was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO I ended up not going with @MikePennington's suggestion (getting AV2). According to the Networking guys I spoke with I had it reversed and though a AV2 system would work, the reason it wasnt working with my existing devids is that I didnt need a WAP (Wireless Access Point) apparently I needed a Bridge. I got a D-Link DAP-1522. Worked pretty nicely. Instructions were a little sketchy but its working perfectly. I decided against AV2 because you have to be plugged into a physical outlet, not a surge supressor or it will not work according to who I talked to.

Answer (score 1):

> So I had a cable modem/router setup through my ISP right in my office. They sold me on TV via IP but when they went to install it, "The Router will have to be placed by the TV". This means all my wired ports were lost...
>
> ... Is there any way to use my existing hardware to wirelessly connect it to my network without physically using a wire across the house.

If it was me, I would look at [Homeplug AV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug); for examples of [Homeplug AV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug) products and throughput, take a look at this [comparison of two Homeplug AV2 options](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/lanwan/lanwan-reviews/32164-homeplug-av2-head-to-head).    [Homeplug AV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug) lets you send ethernet packets through your house power wiring, as long as you hook up some [Homeplug AV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug) transceivers on both sides.  I still have the original Homeplug AV standard running in my house, and it is great when a physical wire is required.

Practically, this means buying two Homeplug AV2 transceivers.  Plug one into the wall in your office, and plug the other into the wall next to your TV.  Then, take ethernet cables and connect the TV / Office wifi router to your new Homeplug AV2 transceivers.  Be sure to turn on encryption on the link, because the [Homeplug AV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug) signals leave you vulnerable to hacking similar to an open wifi would.

Fixing the cabling issue should be relatively painless; please let me know how this works out for you.